# Image With Relative Path Not Displaying

Tags: html

I am currently trying to display a image with a relative path, and it is not working! The path I am trying is:

```
pictures/picture.png
```

Yet it always says the image does not exist. Then I will even try:

```
sitename/profiles/pictures/picture.png
```

Still does not work. Then I will finally try:

```
http://localhost/sitename/profiles/pictures/picture.png
```

And it finally works. I am trying to display it like this:

```
<img src="pictures/picture.png" />
```

Why would the relative paths not be working? Please help!!! :(

**UPDATE**
Here are my directorys:

```
Sitename
  Profiles
    Pictures
      image.png
    ProfilesPicture <--- Where I want to run the image
```

Comment: In the working path there is a folder `profiles/`. You have to include it to the relative path.

Comment: <img src="profiles/pictures/picture.png" /> does not work :(

Comment: Which is the URL of the page where you use the image?

Comment: Try <img src="../profiles/pictures/picture.png" /> if your HTML file is located inside ProfilesPicture folder.

Comment: ../profiles/pictures/picture.png does not work :(

Comment: Where is your html file located?

Comment: The HTML File is the ProfilesPicture, and it is located in the Profiles folder with the pictures folder.

Comment: Aham. That means `<img src="../profiles/pictures/picture.png" />` this isn't solution at all. According it's HTML, have you tried without calling server on localhost? I mean just to open html file in browser and put in code relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems after you all helping me, especially @Afshin, I was able to solve my problem! :) The correct SRC is **../pictures/picture.png**. I found this out by copying the image location in the browser! :D

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
<img src="http://localhost/sitename/profiles/pictures/picture.png">
```